# calling a class without () is working fine but not giving desired output

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, can anyone please explain to me why this is happening??
What is the meaning of "()"

```
class ganga:
    a ="subhanshu"
    def course(self,name):
        self.ab = name
obj1=ganga()                #it works fine
obj = ganga                 #works fine
obj1.course("apple")        #it works fine
onj.course("apple")         #gives me error
```

error is:
**TypeError: course() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'**

Comment: please learn about the basics of object-oriented python... there are so many ressources out there. e.g. this: https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `course` has two arguments: `self` and `name`. The `self` argument refers to the object on which to perform the function's operation.

### Case #1

```py
obj1 = ganga()
```

You created an object of the class `ganga`. When you called the function via the object `obj1.course("apple")`, the `self` argument was automatically filled in as `obj1`.

### Case #2

```py
obj = ganga
```

Here you made a copy of the class `ganga` and assigned it to the variable. Therfore, when you called the function, it expects you to specify both the arguments. Try the following -

```py
obj1 = ganga()
obj.course(obj1, "apple")
```

This perform the `course` operation on `obj1`.